# URL links work in test but not in actuality - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, hyperlink

I have URL links set up on buttons and TLF text. When I test the movie in Flash the links behave as expected. All the websites open up without an issue. However, when I open the .SWF file from Windows Explorer, none of the links function. I did find the answer to how to fix the URL links by setting the Publish settings Local Playback Security to "Access Network Only" but now my internal linkage system doesn't work. 
The way my program works is:
I have buttons that import an external SWF file through the "addchild" script. Then inside the loaded swf there are text links that point to URLS. With the 'Local Playback Security' set to "Access Local Only" the program will load the external SWF files but not link to the URLS. Then if I set the 'Local Playback Security' to "Access Network Only" the program will not load the SWF files; but when I open the SWF in explorer, the links work. I need both to work. I think it's dumb that there isn't an option to "Access both Local and Network"

Is there another way to fix this?

If you need to see code I can post it, but it is the most basic way to make these actions work. I'm just learning.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the localhost with WAMP server.